# Trying to multiply the kiddy way

Tags: c++

I'm supposed to multiply two 3-digit numbers the way we used to do in childhood.
I need to multiply each digit of a number with each of the other number's digit, calculate the carry, add the individual products and store the result.
I was able to store the 3 products obtained (for I/P 234 and 456):
1404
1170
0936
..in a 2D array.

Now when I try to arrange them in the following manner:
001404
011700
093600
to ease addition to get the result; by:

```
for(j=5;j>1;j--)
{
    xx[0][j]=xx[0][j-2];
}
for(j=4;j>0;j--)
{
    xx[1][j]=xx[1][j-1];
}
```

xx is the 2D array I've stored the 3 products in.
everything seems to be going fine till I do this:

```
xx[0][0]=0;
xx[0][1]=0;
xx[1][0]=0;
```

Here's when things go awry. The values get all mashed up. On printing, I get 001400 041700 093604.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific :) What is `xx`? What do you mean by "all mashed up"? Perhaps type out what `xx` looks and what the incorrect output looks like :)

Comment: Ahaha. Sorry about that = )

Comment: Could you post the code you use to allocate/declare the array? Your solution seems to work logically so I think it might be a memory allocation problem or something of that nature.

Comment: @Matthew I used `int xx[3][5]`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the first index of `xx` is the partial sum, that the second index is the digit in that sum, and that the partial sums are stored with the highest digit at the lowest index,

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_DIGITS; i++) // NUM_DIGITS = number of digits in multiplicands
{
    for (int j = 5; j >= 0; j--) // Assuming 5 is big enough
    {
        int index = (j - 1) - (NUM_DIGITS - 1) - i;
        xx[i][j] = index >= 0 ? xx[i][index] : 0;
    }
}
```

There are definitely more efficient/logical ways of doing this, of course, such as avoiding storing the digits individually, but within the constraints of the problem, this should give you the right answer.

Comment: Could you explain this in a bit more detail? I'm not sure I understand. Also, I stored them individually in case the answer becomes too large for any datatype. I'm solving this question to try and understand how to store large products; I need to be able to calculate the factorial of large numbers for the real problem.

Comment: Sure, I can elaborate.  Which detail is confusing you?